# Unable to run test with VertxUnitRunner

Tags: vert.x

I am new to the Vertx Unit and trying to run the below example, but with no luck

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class DemoTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before(TestContext context) {
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingElse(TestContext context) {
        System.out.println("testSomethingElse");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after(TestContext context) {
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}
```

I am running using `mvn clean test`

Receiving the following output

```
Running com.example.DemoTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by adding the JUnit dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look as well to the maven-surefire-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) and add it to your pom.xml, here I post some mvn commands to test:

```
# Run all the unit test classes.
$ mvn test

# Run a single test class.
$ mvn -Dtest=TestApp1 test

# Run multiple test classes.
$ mvn -Dtest=TestApp1,TestApp2 test

# Run a single test method from a test class.
$ mvn -Dtest=TestApp1#methodname test

# Run all test methods that match pattern 'testHello*' from a test class.
$ mvn -Dtest=TestApp1#testHello* test

# Run all test methods match pattern 'testHello*' and 'testMagic*' from a test class.
$ mvn -Dtest=TestApp1#testHello*+testMagic* test
```

Comment: Not needed was able to solve it using below ans
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62893049/6516761